# Kubenetes doesn't recover service after minion failure

Tags: containers, kubernetes

I am testing Kubernetes redundancy features with a testbed made of one master and three minions.

**Case:** I am running a service with 3 replicas on minions 1 and 2 and minion3 stopped

[root@centos-master ajn]# `kubectl get nodes`

> NAME STATUS AGE
>   centos-minion3 NotReady 14d
>   centos-minion1 Ready 14d
>   centos-minion2 Ready 14d

[root@centos-master ajn]# `kubectl describe pods $MYPODS | grep Node:`

> Node:    centos-minion2/192.168.0.107
>   Node:    centos-minion1/192.168.0.155
>   Node:    centos-minion2/192.168.0.107

**Test:** After starting minion3 and stopping minion2 (on which 2 pods are running)

[root@centos-master ajn]# `kubectl get nodes`

> NAME STATUS AGE
>   centos-minion3 Ready 15d
>   centos-minion1 Ready 14d
>   centos-minion2 NotReady 14d

**Result:** The service kind doesn't recover from minion failure and Kubernetes continue showing pods on the failed minion.

[root@centos-master ajn]# `kubectl describe pods $MYPODS | grep Node:`

> Node:    centos-minion2/192.168.0.107
>   Node:    centos-minion1/192.168.0.155
>   Node:    centos-minion2/192.168.0.107

**Expected result (at least in my understanding):** the service should have been built on the currently available minion 1 and 3

As far as I understand, the role of service kind is to make the deployment "globally" available so we can refer to them independently of where deployments are in the cluster.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

I'm using the follwoing yaml spec:

apiVersion: v1
 kind: ReplicationController
 metadata:
   name: nginx-www 
 spec:
   replicas: 3
   selector:
     app:  nginx
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: nginx
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: nginx
         image: nginx
         ports:
         - containerPort: 80

Comment: You can see nodes that pods run on by doing `kubectl get pods -o wide`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're always trying to read the same pods that are referenced in `$MYPODS`. Pod names are created dynamically by the ReplicationController, so instead of `kubectl describe pods $MYPODS` try this instead:

`kubectl get pods -l app=nginx -o wide`

This will always give you the currently scheduled pods for your app.